# Completely muting notifications while leaving the ringtone on vibration

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notifications, vibration, lg-g2, silent-mode

I have an LG G2. I'd like to completely mute notifications, while leaving the ringtone on vibration.

I know I can set different volumes to notifications and ringtone, but the lowest the notifications go independently is vibration, so if I want to silence them completely I have to silence the ringtone, too.

I also know that most apps have an option to enable or disable vibration on notifications, but I'd like a temporary, system-wide, easy to change option.

¿Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have been using an app called Power Toggles, which has a widget for changing various sound settings. This widget can be placed on your home screen. You may want to try it out.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en

Comment: I tried it but it didn't solve my problem. I can put both notifications and ringtone in vibration or mute, but not just notifications.